# How can I get Amazon Instant Video to work?

Tags: flash, google-chrome, amazon

I have flash, which seems to have dead ended at 11.2.  I have the latest chrome 23.xxx.x..x, but neither of those allow me to watch Amazon Instant video.  I can disable pepper, but then the 11.2 on my system is out of date.

Is there any way I can get Amazon Instant video to work?

Comment: We really can't tell you what other companies are doing. Most likely they won't do anything at all. We might be able to tell you how to get Amazon Instant video working however. Also, why exactly can you not watch AIV? Does it give you any errors?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  An amazon popup tells me to disable PPAPI (Pepper) .  Pepper is currently 11.7.  The system flash is 11.2, which it tries to use if I disable Pepper.  However, 11.2 is too outdated to work with Amazon instant video, and Pepper doesn't support DRM, so it's instantly kicked.  This is foul play.  I don't see any fix, as I can't upgrade 11.2 (upgrades by flash are officially discontinued past 11.2 for linux), and Pepper doesn't support the DRM that amazon requires.

Comment: Ok, Amazon fixed it.  I wrote them a nasty letter.  Whatever arrangement they made with Flash 11.2 and their viewer, seems to work.

Comment: That's great! Can you add that as an answer so others know?

Comment: Sorry, Seth, just saw this.  How do I add it as an answer?

Comment: There should be a "answer your question" button near the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon fixed the issue. It took their development team a little bit of time, but they made the new viewer backwards compatible to 11.2 for Linux.  I did write them a nasty email about it as well.  If it was free, the time wouldn't be an issue, but amazon prime is a costly service, and they should treat it as such.  It's annoying to be put in the back seat as a linux user, and it's nice to see a quick response time from a company like this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was having this same issue lately, after an apparent update. 
I followed this info and it is working great in Linux Mint .
Follow the Ubuntu ppa addition and this will cause firefox to install sliverlight plugin.

http://thelinuxcauldron.com/2013/08/19/youre-doing-it-right-netflx-playback-on-linux-with-pipelight/